# How to redefine \s to match underscores?

Tags: regex, perl, character-class

Perl (< v5.18) regular expression character class `\s` for whitespace is the same as `[\t\n\f\r ]`.

Now, since some filenames use underscore as spaces, I was wondering if it's possible to redefine `\s` (locally) to match underscores in addition to whitespaces.

This would be merely for the sake of readability of otherwise convoluted regular expressions having many `[\s_]`. Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: IMHO, changing the meaning of \s to silently behave in a non-standard way would harm readability, not improve it. Even if you clearly document this in the comments, it requires anyone reading your code to remember that every time they see \s, they need to mentally replace it with [\s_].

Comment: `$s=qr/[\s_]/;`

Comment: The offhand way its done is using qr in custom overloads. See `Creating Custom RE Engines` from the perlre docs.

Comment: In *ASCII only*, `\s` matches `[\t\n\x0B\f\r ]`. `\x0B` is a *vertical tab* character or *line tabulation*. In Unicode it matches another 18 extended characters

Comment: Overriding qr would be very complicated.  You can actually create custom properties quite easily

Comment: You could use the `(?(DEFINE)(?<MY_PATTERN>...))` mechanism, but that'd end up uglier than `[\s_]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever I think that something is impossible in Perl, it usually turns out that I am wrong. And sometimes when I think that something is very difficult in Perl, I am wrong, too. @sln pointed me to the [right track](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlre.pod#Creating-Custom-RE-Engines)

Let's not override `\s` just yet, although you could. For the sake of the heirs of your program who expect `\s` to mean something specific, instead let's define the sequence `\_` to mean "any whitespace character or the `_` character" inside a regular expression. The details are in the link above, but the implementation looks like:

```
package myspace;  # redefine  \_  to mean  [\s_]
use overload;
my %rules = ('\\' => '\\\\', '_' => qr/[\t\n\x{0B}\f\r _]/ );
sub import {
    die if @_ > 1;
    overload::constant 'qr' => sub {
        my $re = shift;
        $re =~ s{\\(\\|_)}{$rules{$1}}gse;
        return $re;
    };
}
1;
```

Now in your script, say

```
use myspace;
```

and now `\_` in a regular expression means `[\s_]`.

Demo:

```
use myspace;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ /aaa\s.*txt/) {      # match whitespace
        print "match[1]: $_\n";
    }
    if ($_ =~ /aaa\_.*txt/) {      # match [\s_]
        print "match[2]: $_\n";
    }
    if ($_ =~ /\\_/) {             # match literal  '\_'
        print "match[3]: $_\n";
    }
}
__DATA__
aaabbb.txt
aaa\_ccc.txt
cccaaa bbb.txt
aaa_bbb.txt
```

Output:

```
match[3]: aaa\_ccc.txt
match[1]: cccaaa bbb.txt
match[2]: cccaaa bbb.txt
match[2]: aaa_bbb.txt
```

The third case is to demonstrate that `\\_` in a regular expression will match a literal `\_`, like `\\s` will match a literal `\s`.

Comment: Noone is using myspace nowadays... :)